# Sorting a list with objects by property

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, lambda

I'm completely stumped, looking around at examples hasn't helped me getting this sort function to work:

```
void sortRegistryByName(std::list<Transcript>& registry) {
   std::sort(registry.begin(), registry.end(), [](const Transcript &f, const Transcript &s) { return f.name < s.name; }); 
}
```

The code above should sort the list of Transcripts by their name property.

And the Transcript is as follows:

```
typedef struct Transcript_t {
    std::string name; // Name of the transcript
    std::string student_id;
    std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> grades; // List of (course, grade) pairs
} Transcript;
```

When I try to compile this the sort function causes one huge wall of errors with something related to safe_iterators and operators.

Anyone see any really really silly mistake here? I'm blind to it.

Comment: `std::sort` requires random-access iterators, `std::list` only provides bidirectional iterators. However, [it has a member `.sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) that you can use instead.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `size_t` here - `std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>> grades;`, and given it's context, you'd probably be better with `std::map<std::string, int>` - assuming there won't be duplicate courses.

Comment: That part isn't my design unfortunately, this is an excersize for a course I'm doing right now and the Transcripts have been given as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `std::list`'s `sort` function since it doesn't have random access iterators:

```
std::list<Transcript> registry;
registry.sort([](const Transcript &f, const Transcript &s) { return f.name < s.name; });
```